# Limiting Instance Type and Request Region in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-iam

I have this case that I want to limit the creation of EC2 Instances to the following conditions:

- Instance Type: `"*.nano", "*.small", "*.micro", "*.medium", "*.large"`
- Region when EC2 is created: `eu-central-1`

I created the following EC2 Policies:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ec2:CreateDhcpOptions",
                "ec2:AuthorizeSecurityGroupIngress",
                "ec2:ModifyVolumeAttribute",
                "ec2:ReplaceRouteTableAssociation",
                "ec2:DeleteVpcEndpoints",
                "ec2:CreateKeyPair",
                "ec2:ResetInstanceAttribute",
                "ec2:AttachInternetGateway",
                "ec2:ReportInstanceStatus",
                "ec2:UpdateSecurityGroupRuleDescriptionsIngress",
                "ec2:DeleteRouteTable",
                "ec2:ModifySpotFleetRequest",
                "ec2:ModifySnapshotAttribute",
                "ec2:DeleteVpnGateway",
                "ec2:CreateNetworkInterfacePermission",
                "ec2:RevokeSecurityGroupEgress",
                "ec2:CreateRoute",
                "ec2:CreateInternetGateway",
                "ec2:DeleteInternetGateway",
                "ec2:UnassignPrivateIpAddresses",
                "ec2:CreateReservedInstancesListing",
                "ec2:CancelExportTask",
                "ec2:BundleInstance",
                "ec2:ImportKeyPair",
                "ec2:ModifyNetworkInterfaceAttribute",
                "ec2:AssignPrivateIpAddresses",
                "ec2:DisassociateRouteTable",
                "ec2:CreateVolume",
                "ec2:ReplaceNetworkAclAssociation",
                "ec2:CreateVpcEndpointServiceConfiguration",
                "ec2:RevokeSecurityGroupIngress",
                "ec2:CreateNetworkInterface",
                "ec2:CancelSpotInstanceRequests",
                "ec2:DetachVpnGateway",
                "ec2:CreateDefaultVpc",
                "ec2:DeleteDhcpOptions",
                "ec2:DeleteNatGateway",
                "ec2:CreateSubnet",
                "ec2:ModifyVpcEndpoint",
                "ec2:DeleteNetworkAclEntry",
                "ec2:CreateVpnConnection",
                "ec2:DeleteSpotDatafeedSubscription",
                "ec2:DisassociateAddress",
                "ec2:ModifyVpcEndpointServicePermissions",
                "ec2:ImportVolume",
                "ec2:MoveAddressToVpc",
                "ec2:CreateNatGateway",
                "ec2:ModifyFleet",
                "ec2:RunScheduledInstances",
                "ec2:ModifyIdentityIdFormat",
                "ec2:CreateVpc",
                "ec2:RequestSpotFleet",
                "ec2:ModifyImageAttribute",
                "ec2:ReleaseHosts",
                "ec2:ModifySubnetAttribute",
                "ec2:CreateDefaultSubnet",
                "ec2:CreateSpotDatafeedSubscription",
                "ec2:CreateSnapshot",
                "ec2:DeleteLaunchTemplateVersions",
                "ec2:DeleteNetworkAcl",
                "ec2:ModifyReservedInstances",
                "ec2:ReleaseAddress",
                "ec2:CreateInstanceExportTask",
                "ec2:DeleteLaunchTemplate",
                "ec2:AssociateDhcpOptions",
                "ec2:ModifyInstancePlacement",
                "ec2:AssignIpv6Addresses",
                "ec2:ImportInstance",
                "ec2:AttachVpnGateway",
                "ec2:AcceptVpcEndpointConnections",
                "ec2:ModifyFpgaImageAttribute",
                "ec2:ResetSnapshotAttribute",
                "ec2:CancelConversionTask",
                "ec2:ImportSnapshot",
                "ec2:CreateVpnConnectionRoute",
                "ec2:DisassociateSubnetCidrBlock",
                "ec2:DeleteVpcEndpointConnectionNotifications",
                "ec2:CreateLaunchTemplate",
                "ec2:RestoreAddressToClassic",
                "ec2:DeleteCustomerGateway",
                "ec2:EnableVgwRoutePropagation",
                "ec2:DisableVpcClassicLink",
                "ec2:DisableVpcClassicLinkDnsSupport",
                "ec2:AllocateHosts",
                "ec2:ModifyVpcTenancy",
                "ec2:CancelImportTask",
                "ec2:ModifyIdFormat",
                "ec2:ConfirmProductInstance",
                "ec2:DeleteFlowLogs",
                "ec2:CopySnapshot",
                "ec2:DeleteSubnet",
                "ec2:ModifyVpcEndpointServiceConfiguration",
                "ec2:UnmonitorInstances",
                "ec2:MonitorInstances",
                "ec2:DeleteVpcPeeringConnection",
                "ec2:AcceptVpcPeeringConnection",
                "ec2:CreateImage",
                "ec2:PurchaseHostReservation",
                "ec2:CopyImage",
                "ec2:DisableVgwRoutePropagation",
                "ec2:AssociateVpcCidrBlock",
                "ec2:ReplaceRoute",
                "ec2:RejectVpcPeeringConnection",
                "ec2:AssociateRouteTable",
                "ec2:DisassociateVpcCidrBlock",
                "ec2:DeleteVolume",
                "ec2:CreatePlacementGroup",
                "ec2:ReplaceNetworkAclEntry",
                "ec2:ModifyVpcPeeringConnectionOptions",
                "ec2:CreateVpnGateway",
                "ec2:UnassignIpv6Addresses",
                "ec2:ImportImage",
                "ec2:DeleteVpnConnection",
                "ec2:CreateVpcPeeringConnection",
                "ec2:RejectVpcEndpointConnections",
                "ec2:EnableVpcClassicLink",
                "ec2:PurchaseScheduledInstances",
                "ec2:ModifyVolume",
                "ec2:ResetImageAttribute",
                "ec2:UpdateSecurityGroupRuleDescriptionsEgress",
                "ec2:CreateVpcEndpointConnectionNotification",
                "ec2:ResetNetworkInterfaceAttribute",
                "ec2:RegisterImage",
                "ec2:CreateRouteTable",
                "ec2:DeleteNetworkInterface",
                "ec2:CreateFleet",
                "ec2:DetachInternetGateway",
                "ec2:CreateCustomerGateway",
                "ec2:ModifyHosts",
                "ec2:ModifyVpcEndpointConnectionNotification",
                "ec2:EnableVolumeIO",
                "ec2:CreateFlowLogs",
                "ec2:AssociateSubnetCidrBlock",
                "ec2:DeleteVpc",
                "ec2:CreateEgressOnlyInternetGateway",
                "ec2:AssociateAddress",
                "ec2:DeleteKeyPair",
                "ec2:CancelBundleTask",
                "ec2:DeregisterImage",
                "ec2:DeleteSnapshot",
                "ec2:PurchaseReservedInstancesOffering",
                "ec2:DeleteTags",
                "ec2:RequestSpotInstances",
                "ec2:CancelSpotFleetRequests",
                "ec2:DeleteFleets",
                "ec2:DeleteVpcEndpointServiceConfigurations",
                "ec2:DeleteFpgaImage",
                "ec2:DeleteNetworkInterfacePermission",
                "ec2:CreateSecurityGroup",
                "ec2:CreateNetworkAcl",
                "ec2:ModifyVpcAttribute",
                "ec2:ModifyInstanceAttribute",
                "ec2:AuthorizeSecurityGroupEgress",
                "ec2:DeleteEgressOnlyInternetGateway",
                "ec2:DetachNetworkInterface",
                "ec2:DeletePlacementGroup",
                "ec2:DeleteRoute",
                "ec2:CopyFpgaImage",
                "ec2:AllocateAddress",
                "ec2:CreateLaunchTemplateVersion",
                "ec2:DeleteVpnConnectionRoute",
                "ec2:ModifyInstanceCreditSpecification",
                "ec2:CreateVpcEndpoint",
                "ec2:DeleteSecurityGroup",
                "ec2:CreateFpgaImage",
                "ec2:AcceptReservedInstancesExchangeQuote",
                "ec2:ModifyLaunchTemplate",
                "ec2:AttachNetworkInterface",
                "ec2:EnableVpcClassicLinkDnsSupport",
                "ec2:CancelReservedInstancesListing",
                "ec2:CreateNetworkAclEntry",
                "ec2:ResetFpgaImageAttribute"
            ],
            "Resource": "*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringLike": {
                    "aws:RequestedRegion": "eu-central-1"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor1",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ec2:DetachVolume",
                "ec2:AttachVolume",
                "ec2:RebootInstances",
                "ec2:AttachClassicLinkVpc",
                "ec2:TerminateInstances",
                "ec2:DetachClassicLinkVpc",
                "ec2:CreateTags",
                "ec2:RunInstances",
                "ec2:StopInstances",
                "ec2:ReplaceIamInstanceProfileAssociation",
                "ec2:StartInstances",
                "ec2:DisassociateIamInstanceProfile",
                "ec2:AssociateIamInstanceProfile"
            ],
            "Resource": "*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringLike": {
                    "aws:RequestedRegion": "eu-central-1",
                    "ec2:InstanceType": [
                        "*.nano",
                        "*.small",
                        "*.micro",
                        "*.medium",
                        "t2.large"
                    ]
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor2",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "ec2:Describe*",
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

I get the following error whenever I create any kind of Instance either the ones mentioned before or any other types:

```
Launch Failed
You are not authorized to perform this operation.
Creating security groups Successful (sg-0f49c6462ba8c1f3b)
Authorizing inbound rules Successful
Initiating launches  Failure
```

Comment: Do you wish to limit it for _all_ users or just a specific set of users? Where did you put the above policy (for example, on your IAM User)?

Comment: Thanks a lot john for your comment, my case would be for a set/group of IAM users, and I assigned this policy it to one user already called _restricted-admin_ just for testing purpose `arn:aws:iam::account-id:user/restricted-admin`

but it seems that launching any type of instances doesn't work anymore for this user

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only Actions that would need to be restricted by Instance Type would be `RunInstances` (to start instances) and `ModifyInstanceAttribute` (to change an instance type).

You are welcome to assign all other permissions unrestricted by instance type, but restricted by region.

From [Amazon EC2: Allows Full EC2 Access Within a Specific Region, Programmatically and in the Console - AWS Identity and Access Management](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_examples_ec2_region.html):

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Action": "ec2:*",
            "Resource": "*",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "ec2:Region": "<REGION>"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

[Easier way to control access to AWS regions using IAM policies | AWS Security Blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/easier-way-to-control-access-to-aws-regions-using-iam-policies/) also shows another way:

```
    {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "ec2:*"
        ],
        "Resource": "*",
        "Condition": {"StringEquals": {"aws:RequestedRegion": "eu-central-1"}}

    },
```

I'm not sure which one is better to use.

Then, to stop the users from launching unwanted instance types, add a `Deny` policy that overrides the allow policy.

From [Limiting Allowed AWS Instance Type With IAM Policy](https://blog.vizuri.com/limiting-allowed-aws-instance-type-with-iam-policy) (which includes wildcards for instance types permitted):

```
    {
        "Sid": "limitedSize",
        "Effect": "Deny",
        "Action": ["ec2:RunInstances", "ec2:ModifyInstanceAttribute"],
        "Resource": "arn:aws:ec2:*:*:instance/*",
        "Condition": {
            "ForAnyValue:StringNotLike": {
                "ec2:InstanceType": [
                    "*.nano",
                    "*.small",
                    "*.micro",
                    "*.medium"
                ]
            }
        }
    }
```

Or, from [How to restrict by regions and instance types in AWS with IAM – : : blyx.com : : Blog : : Toni de la Fuente](https://blyx.com/2016/03/24/how-to-restrict-by-regions-and-instance-types-in-aws-with-iam/) (which states which instance types are *not* allowed):

```
{
    "Sid": "OnlyAllowCertainInstanceTypesToBeCreated",
    "Effect": "Deny",
    "Action": [
        "ec2:RunInstances",
        "ec2:ModifyInstanceAttribute",
    ],
    "Resource": "*",
    "Condition": {
        "StringEquals": {
            "ec2:InstanceType": [
                "m2.xlarge",
                "cg1.4xlarge",
                "c3.4xlarge"
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Perfect, worked like charm, the mentioned policies restricted the Instance Type and the Instance Region for the EC2 service.

Thanks a lot @John, Have a great day.